# Java-webservice: Glassfish3.0 error "org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

While I restarting the Glassfish 3.0 server from NetBeans 8.0 after adding a RESTful web service, I got this exception and couldn't request the web service!!

```
Glassfish 3.0: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
```

I checked the Maven Pom.xml for jersey dependency and the tag is already exist!

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your exact setup but the problem is that you are providing **Jersey/Jackson 2.x** libs but you are obviously using **Jersey/Jackson 1.x**.

Note that **Glassfish 3.x** comes with **Jersey/Jackson 1.x** by default (**Glassfish 4.x** comes with **Jersey/Jackson 2.x** by default).

The error message shows it can't find class **org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider**.

The **org.codehaus** classes are indicating **Jersey/Jackson 1.x**. In **Jersey/Jackson 2.x** the classes are in the package **com.fasterxml** (like in the dependency you are providing).

Try the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

and remove the other dependency.

Comment: When I use the above tag I got this exception: Failed to execute goal on project: Could not resolve dependencies for project :ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:1.9.13, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:1.9.13, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:1.9.13, com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:1.9.13, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:ja

Comment: r:1.9.13: Failure to find com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:1.9.13 in file:C:\NetBeansProjects\Projrct/lib was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of unknown-jars-temp-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]